# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje de error si la busqueda no coincide con los registros de la BD?

Tags: c#

```
private void BuscarIdLibro()
    {
        try
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtBusquedas.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe llenar los campos requeridos",
                       "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }
            List<Libros> listaLibros = new List<Libros>();
            listaLibros = new            LibrosBLReporte().BuscarIDLibro(TxtBusquedas.Text);
            this.DGVRepLibros.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.DGVRepLibros.DataSource = listaLibrosNInsc;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino te refieres a informar cuando no hay libros en la lista que carga el grid, quizas algo como esto

```
private void BuscarIdLibro()
{
    try
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtBusquedas.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Debe llenar los campos requeridos",
                   "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
        List<Libros> listaLibros = new LibrosBLReporte().BuscarIDLibro(TxtBusquedas.Text);

        if(listaLibros.Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron libros para el filtro proporcionado");
            return;
        }

        this.DGVRepLibros.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        this.DGVRepLibros.DataSource = listaLibrosNInsc;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

basicamente evaluas si la lista tiene algun item, sino lo tiene lo informas y no continuas asignardo el grid